# How to download Landsat 5 specific band using Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, download, landsat-5

I am trying to download Landsat 5 Band 6 using `Google Earth Engine`. When I run the code I am getting the following error: `Error: Invalid argument: 'image' must be of type Image`. I found on this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/292691/earth-engine-error-error-invalid-argument-image-must-be-of-type-image/292695) that I was trying to export an `ImageCollection` instead of a single image. I also found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48167363/google-earth-engine-specify-bands-in-ee-image-getdownloadurl) but the `getDownloadURL` is not working. I would like to ask, because I am new to `GEE` how can I download a single band? Below it's the code:

```
   var sub_geom = region.geometry();
    var sub_region = JSON.stringify(sub_geom.bounds(1).getInfo().coordinates);

Map.addLayer(sub_geom);
var cloudMaskL457 = function(image) {
  var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');
  // If the cloud bit (5) is set and the cloud confidence (7) is high
  // or the cloud shadow bit is set (3), then it's a bad pixel.
  var cloud = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 5)
                  .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 7))
                  .or(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 3));
  // Remove edge pixels that don't occur in all bands
  var mask2 = image.mask().reduce(ee.Reducer.min());
  return image.updateMask(cloud.not()).updateMask(mask2);
};
//Import Landsat Image
var L7200508NDVI = ee.Image(ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_SR')
.filterDate('1995-01-01', '1995-01-31')
.map(cloudMaskL457)
.filterBounds(sub_geom)
.mean());

// Export the image, specifying scale and region.
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: L7200508NDVI,
  description: 'imageToDriveExample',
  scale: 120,
  region: sub_geom
});
```

Comment: Your code runs successfully for me, although I would have used a different region geometry. I suppose you've checked that your region overlaps some images? Also, it outputs an 11-band image. To get only band 6, similar to how you select the pixel_qa band, you can `L7200508NDVI.select("B6")` to get band 6.

Comment: Same here, it runs with a different region.

Comment: The code runs successfully but when I try to download the images I get the error I mentioned. Because I am struggling for some time now to download the Band 6, can you please specify at which line I should include `L7200508NDVI.select("B6")`? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by @phloem, I added the `L7200508NDVI.select("B6")`, I removed the first three lines of my code, I import a polygon `shp` from the `Assets` and I was able to download the image. Below is the code:

```
var cloudMaskL457 = function(image) {
  var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');
  // If the cloud bit (5) is set and the cloud confidence (7) is high
  // or the cloud shadow bit is set (3), then it's a bad pixel.
  var cloud = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 5)
                  .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 7))
                  .or(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 3));
  // Remove edge pixels that don't occur in all bands
  var mask2 = image.mask().reduce(ee.Reducer.min());
  return image.updateMask(cloud.not()).updateMask(mask2);
};
//Import Landsat Image
var L7200508NDVI = ee.Image(ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_SR')
.filterDate('1995-01-01', '1995-01-31')
.map(cloudMaskL457)
.filterBounds(table)
.mean());

var b6 = L7200508NDVI.select("B6")

// Export the image, specifying scale and region.
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: b6,
  description: 'b6',
  scale: 120,
  region: table
});
```