# Downloading EVI from Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, landsat-8, evi

I am trying to download images from Landsat's EVI collection off of Google Earth Engine. I saw another similar post here: [EVI or NDVI collection image download](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/384796/evi-or-ndvi-collection-image-download) that talked about the same issue. One response was to create a "for loop", which I have done. When I run my code though, nothing happens. I get no errors but also nothing is downloaded and there are no tasks. What am I doing wrong? I am new to google earth engine.

```
// Exporting Landsat 8 Images

var roi = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([-150.0, 8.0, -34.0, 84.0]);

// Load EVI collection
var eviCol = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_8DAY_EVI") 
.filterDate('2022-05-01', '2022-08-31')
.filterBounds(roi)
.sort('CLOUD_COVER')
.select('EVI');

var eviList = eviCol.toList(eviCol.size());

var colorizedVis = {
  min: 0,
  max: 1,
  palette: [
    'ffffff', 'ce7e45', 'df923d', 'f1b555', 'fcd163', '99b718', '74a901',
    '66a000', '529400', '3e8601', '207401', '056201', '004c00', '023b01',
    '012e01', '011d01', '011301'
  ],
};

for (var i = 0; i < eviCol.size().getInfo; i++) {
  var image = ee.Image(eviList.get(i));
 
  // Add the colorized EVI layer to the map
  Map.addLayer(image.clip(roi), colorizedVis, 'Colorized');
  
  // Export to Drive with consistent visualization settings
  Export.image.toDrive({
    image: image,
    description: 'Landsat2022_NA' + i,
    scale: 30,
    region: roi,
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three issues with your code in the dataset and the for loop.

1. According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/LANDSAT_LC08_C01_T1_8DAY_EVI#bands), there is no data after 2022-01-01. However, you have given date range after that period.
2. There is no 'CLOUD_COVER' property in the image collection. You can check from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/LANDSAT_LC08_C01_T1_8DAY_EVI#bands).
3. In the for loop, parenthesis is missing after the `getInfo()` method. The correct one would be `eviCol.size().getInfo()`

Comment: This worked. Thank you! I see what you are saying about the date availability and cloud cover properties now. I will be sure to double check these details in the future.